# Query to check relationships between columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a table called User_Followers this table has the following columns:

User_Id
Follower_Id

I'm trying to build a query that will retrieve all the people a user is following but no being followed back by.

For example:

```
User ID | Follower ID

1              2
1              4
3              1
4              2
4              3
```

In the example above, if I was to check for users not following back User 4. It should return 1.

Similarly if I was to check for users not following back User 2, it should return 1 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to build a query that will retrieve all the people a user is following but no being followed back by.

If I understand correctly, then `not exists` seems to do what you want:

```
select uf.user_id
from User_Followers uf
where uf.follower_id = @user and
      not exists (select 1
                  from User_Followers uf2
                  where uf2.user_id = uf.follower_id and
                        uf2.follower_id = uf.user_id
                 );
```

Comment: `SELECT User_Id FROM User_Followers WHERE User_Id NOT IN (SELECT User_Id FROM User_Followers WHERE Follower_Id = @FollowerId)` works too?

Comment: @Paul.F-G rather `WHERE User_Id NOT IN (SELECT Follower_Id ...` Check my answer, but Gordon's one is good (my upvote), I always have a naive approach

Comment: @Paul.F-G . . . I would strongly discourage you from using `NOT IN` with a subquery.  It does not work as you would expect if *any* of the returned values are `NULL`.  Although it might work in this situation, you may find problems in the future.  Just use `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 queries :

*"being followed"* can be written this way :

```
SELECT u.Follower_Id
FROM User_Followers u
WHERE u.User_Id = ?
```

*"all the people a user is following"* can be done this way :

```
SELECT u.User_Id 
FROM User_Followers u
WHERE u.Follower_Id = ?
```

---

Now, you can combine both queries to perform the *"all the people a user is following"* **and not** *"being followed"*

```
SELECT u.User_Id 
FROM User_Followers u
WHERE u.Follower_Id = ?
AND u.User_Id NOT IN
(
    SELECT uf.Follower_Id
    FROM User_Followers uf
    WHERE uf.User_Id = ?
)
```